# Create archive of complete drive with tar

Tags: tar

I want to backup my complete drive of my brand new PC.

I tried this command:

```
sudo tar -czvf disk.tar /dev/nvme0n1
```

But it finishes after 1 second.

The nvme0n1 file in the archive is 0 bytes.

What is wrong here?

Edit:

I always run this command on the partition before so I have no (already deleted) files:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=moh bs=100M
rm moh
```

Comment: The input isn't a file or directory: `/dev/nvme0n1` (just as well, since the output is probably on the same disk...).

Comment: The output is on a different disk. So tar isn't capable of archiving block devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tar` should be used to backup files. To backup a exact state of a disk you should use `dd`.

So if you want a **exact** copy of the drive use:
`dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/mnt/some_other_drive/copy_of_the_first_drive`.

Even better would be to use compression (if it's a disk of a brand new pc you can strongly compress it) with `dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 | bzip2 > /mnt/some_other_drive/copy_of_the_first_drive.bz2`

Lot's of other options are also possible:

- You could use `nc` or `ssh` to create a tunnel and transfer the backup to another system while it's being made (if there is no 2nd disk on your system).
- You could use `tar` if you only want the files and not the whole state
- You could use `rsync` if you only want the files and there is no 2nd disk available.

Comment: Is it possible to pipe /dev/nvme0n1 into tar, as you did with bzip2?

Comment: Yes but there is no added advantage. `tar` is only useful for multiple files and `/dev/nvme0n` is only 1 'file' (it's treated as 1 file by the system). `tar` just places a lot of files behind each other and saves them as 1 file. It has no compression other useful features.

Comment: The bzip2 command does not work. It says "Can't open input file"

Comment: Sorry, the `>` was missing, i edited it

Comment: How would you extract bz2 backup?

Comment: `bunzip2 copy_of_the_first_drive.bz2`

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should mount it to a directory like /mnt.
after that u can use your command(tar czvf somebackup.tar.gz /mnt).
anyway i suggest you to work with rsync.
if you wanna pick whole state up to another hard disk you should use dd command else you have not to do so.

Comment: I also need to backup data which is not stored in files (for example MBR). So mount/cp is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

### `tar` is intended to work on the file level

You can use `tar` to create an archive of directories and files, and the archive may or may not be compressed.

This way you can backup the content of the root partition, **/**, and other partition(s), that you may have in your system.

Examples (run when running another system, e.g. booted from a USB pendrive)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sd1
sudo mkdir /mnt/sd2
sudo mkdir /mnt/sd3

sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/sd1
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/sd2
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/sd3

sudo tar -cvzf root.tar.gz /mnt/sd1
sudo tar -cvzf home.tar.gz /mnt/sd2  # optional
sudo tar -cvzf data.tar.gz /mnt/sd3  # optional
```

It is easy to access a single backed up file, particularly if you do not compress the archive. This is good.

But the partition table (and BIOS bootloader (necessary to boot in BIOS mode)) will *not* be backed up.

### Clonezilla works on a whole drive

You can use [**Clonezilla**](https://clonezilla.org), which is a tool to clone or create a [compressed] image of the content of a whole drive with partitions and bootloaders, everything.

- Download a Clonezilla iso file,
- create a USB boot drive,
- boot from it and
- let Clonezilla do it for you.

Clonezilla is smart enough to only copy used blocks in the file system(s) and skip free space. It will also compress the image, so it is both faster and creates a much smaller image (compared to plain cloning with for example `dd`). The image is not one file, but a directory with a set of files, and you use Clonezilla to restore from the image.

Clonezilla has also several checkpoints to help you identify the drives and make sure that, when backing up, you are reading from the correct drive, and when restoring, that you are writing to the correct drive.

Comment: I don't like clonezilla because it's a huge program with complicated file formats (check points and so on). I have used blocks only too (see my update).

Comment: I see. We have different preferences concerning checkpoints etc. Good luck with the `dd` method :-)